# How to display offline OpenStreetMap using MapView on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, openstreetmap

How to display OpenStreetMap offline using MapView on Android? What should I do to load a map?

Comment: By "MapView" I guess you mean this type of View in the android SDK: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html So the question is whether and how you can define a layer to make this read tiles images from a local store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OpenStreetMap contain a large amout of data, you need to select a subset of it and probably transform the OSM XML to your own vector format that require less storage. Then you need to render your own vector format on a canvas.